# Quark Combination of Hadrons

Tags: standard-model, fermions, spinors, quarks, mesons

I am trying to understand the different combinations of quarks in a hadron. I have seen that the positive pion is written as $\pi^{+}=u\bar{d}$, but I have not seen it written in the opposite order. Can we write it as $\pi^{+}=\bar{d}u$?

Further, all the quarks are fermions. So, they can be represented by a four component Dirac spinor, which is a column matrix for particles and a row matrix for antiparticles. If we consider the expression for the positive pion in terms of quarks as a tensor product, then both $u\bar{d}$ and $\bar{d}u$ are $4\times 4$ matrices. Is this combination (the expression of pion) really a tensor product? What in the case of baryons, such as $p=uud$? Are they solid matrices (a rank 3 tensor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing two different things:

If you see the notation $\pi^+ = u \bar{d}$ (e.g. in the Particle Data Tables), this simply means that the quark content of a charged pion is given by an up-quark (with electromagnetic charge $2/3$) and an anti down-quark (with electromagnetic charge $1/3$). In this case, you could equally well write $\pi^+ = \bar{d} u$.

On the other hand, if you are talking about the corresponding *field operators* $u(x)$ and $d(x)$ in quantum chromodynamics (QCD), these objects carry  colour indices $i= r,b,g$ related to the three "colours" $r$(ead), $b$(lue), $g$(reen)  of the fundamental representation of the local gauge group $\text SU(3)_c$ of QCD and, in addition, Dirac indices $\alpha = 1,2,3,4$ related to the spinor character of the operator. Written in full glory, the field operators of the two quarks are objects of the form $u_{i \alpha}(x)$ and $d_{i \alpha}(x)$, respectively. However, these quark field operators do not yet correspond to observable quantities. Operators corresponding to *asymptotic states* (hadrons) must be colour singlets (i.e. they have to be colour neutral). In the case of $\pi^+$, the *colour-neutral* interpolating fields $$A^\mu(x)=\sum\limits_{i, \alpha,\beta}\bar{d}_{\!i \alpha}(x) (\gamma^\mu \gamma_5)_{\alpha \beta} u_{i \beta}(x)\equiv \bar{d}(x) \gamma^\mu \gamma_5 u(x) \tag{1} \label{1}$$ or $$P(x) =\sum\limits_{i, \alpha,\beta}\bar{d}_{\! i \alpha}(x) (\gamma_5)_{\alpha \beta} u_{i \beta}(x)\equiv \bar{d}(x)\gamma_5 u(x) \tag{2} \label{2}$$ can be used. In this case, the order of the *field operators* $\bar{d}(x)$ and $u(x)$ is of course relevant. Note also that all Dirac indices in \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} are contracted (no free Dirac indices left!) arriving at a pseudo-vector operator in \eqref{1} and a pseudo-scalar operator in \eqref{2} (remember that the pions are *pseudo* scalars). Analogous constructions can be performed for other hadrons (like the proton).