# Quark condensate and VEV of $\pi^0$

Tags: standard-model, vacuum, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, pions

In [David Tong's lectures on the Standard Model](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/standardmodel.html) I saw that there is a quark condensate, which is just a Vacuum Expectation Value (VEV) of the $\bar{q}_{Li}\, q_{Ri}$ operator,
$$
 \left< \bar{q}_{Li}\, q_{Ri} \right> = - A \delta_{ij} \, . \tag{3.47}
$$

Now, this leads me to think that there might also be a VEV for the $\pi^0$, which is composed of the linear combination
$$
\pi^0 \equiv \dfrac{u \bar{u} - d \bar{d}}{\sqrt{2}} \, .
$$

I don't think there are any reason why this would be forbidden, as it seems like the vacuum "can give you the needed energy", and it doesn't seem like we are violating any of the QCD symmetries (like Isospin!).

So, am I right? And, if so, how can I compute the VEV of the 0-pion
$$
\left<\pi^0 \right> \equiv \left<\dfrac{u \bar{u} - d \bar{d}}{\sqrt{2}} \right>\, ?
$$

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/806685

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nonono! You've made a bad hash of standard notation.

The interpolating operator for the neutral pion you wrote is far too schematic/complacent, and lacks an all-important $\gamma^5$. You might consider $(\bar u \gamma^5 u - \bar d \gamma^5 d)/\sqrt 2$.

QCD, of course, supports a [scalar condensate of quarks](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0210398) triggering spontaneous chiral symmetry breaking, but not a pseudo-scalar one, as the QCD vacuum ***does not break parity***!
Specifically, $\langle \Omega| \pi^0|\Omega\rangle=  
\langle \Omega|\Pi^\dagger  \pi^0  \Pi|\Omega\rangle=-\langle \Omega| \pi^0|\Omega\rangle$ so that $\langle \pi^0\rangle=0$.

It is more complicated than that, covered in good QFT books. The neutral pion *is* the pseudogoldstone boson of the SSBroken  axial charge $\int d^3x~~\bar q \gamma^5 \gamma^0 \tau^3 q$, so it pops into and out of the roiling QCD vacuum, a much longer story.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Though, are you sure that the $\pi^0$ is the pseudo-Goldstone of the $U(1)_A$? Isn't that the $\eta'$? I believe that the $\pi^0$ comes from the breaking of $SU(2)_L \times SU(2)_R$.

Comment: Yes, you should be sure too. You ignored the $\tau^3$ in the axial charge I wrote. It is *not* the $U(1)_A$ generator. It is the 3rd component of the $\vec R- \vec L$ generators in the chiral group, one of the three spontaneously/dynamically broken ones.